# How can I encode a Process in C# to send by Sockets?

Tags: c#, sockets, process, encode, receiver

I'm a junior programmer. I need to send by Sockets a Process between a Windows Service and a WPF. I want to know how can I encode a Process to send and execute it in the Service. Actually I know how I can send a String or a Integer, but no how to send a Process like:

`````
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    FileName = shell,
                    Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\""
                }
            };````

To encode a String I use:
````// Connect to Remote EndPoint
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                    sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                // Encode the data string into a byte array.
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is a test<EOF>");

                // Send the data through the socket.
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);````

There is some Encode.(Function)? I have to create a new function?
Thank you!
`````

Comment: You can't. The `Process` class has internal state, which would not survive the encoding/decoding, even if you could pull that off. Without further info, I would suggest sending the PID and ProcessStartTime between WPF-GUI and Windows Service Either one can then use the PID to  do `Process.GetProcessById()` (add additionally check if the StartTime is the same as the expected one - Process IDs are recycled).

Comment: And, Can I encode and send just the Process StarInfo?

Comment: You don't need the whole start info. It will be of no particular use. Just send `Process.ProcessId` (int) and `Process.StartTime` (DateTime). For "encoding" consider some sort of "serializer" (Json, XML, etc.).